# Metal intersection_query distance to candidate primitive

Tags: ios, metal

I am using `intersection_query` from Metal's raytracing apis to intersect an acceleration structure of axis aligned bounding boxes. In my shader, I am trying to find the distance where the intersection takes place. Example code:

```
ray r = ...;
primitive_acceleration_structure accelerationStructure = ...;

intersection_query<> i(r, accelerationStructure);
while (i.next()) {
   float distance = // ???
   ...
}
```

However I can't find how to get this distance from the `intersection_query`. For triangle data there's `get_candidate_triangle_distance()`, but there is no `get_candidate_primitive_distance()`.

Is there a fast builtin way to get this distance or do I have to implement this calculation myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the distance to the bounding box in either intersection function or intersection query.

In fact, you **need** to calculate it yourself to provide to `commit_bounding_box_intersection()` or return from an `[[intersection(bounding_box)]]` function.

Comment: Maybe so but this is not very helpful. You can definitely compute this yourself even if metal doesn't expose it

Comment: Not only you can, you need to do it to commit the bounding box intersection. The question was if there's a way to get this distance apart from calculating it yourself and the answer is simply "No".